# Saving a URL to camera roll

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

If I store my images in firebase in a URL form, how could I then save them to my actual iPhones camera roll?

In another project I used the following code to save images, however this doesn't work with the URL

```
guard let image = UIImage(data: photo.image ) else{return}

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
    
print("saved Successfully....")
```

Comment: See [`UIImage init?(contentsOfFile:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624112-init)

Comment: I prefer `let data = try Data(contentsOf: url); let image = UIImage(data: data)`, since it gives you an ability to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // The URL of the image to be saved
        let imageUrl = URL(string: "https://example.com/image.png")!
        
        // Download the image data
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) {
                
                // Save the image to the Camera Roll
                PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)!
                    PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAsset(from: image)
                }) { success, error in
                    if success {
                        print("Image saved to Camera Roll!")
                    } else {
                        print("Error saving image to Camera Roll: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
                
            } else {
                print("Error downloading image data")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Data(contentsOf:)` for remote URLs, only local URLs. Use `URLSession` to load the remote data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).